# Getting a particular subset of methods from a Python class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have read other posts in Stack Overflow that answer this question, but I am interested in a specific subset of methods.

Suppose you have a class `Cn` with `n` higher than 1, as well as classes `C0`, `C1`, ..., `Cn-1` such that, for each `i` between 1 and `n-1`, class `Ci+1` inherits from class `Ci`.

My question is: **for any `i` higher than 1, how can I obtain the list of methods that belong to `Ci` but not to `Ci-1`**?

Comment: So you want all methods on a given that are not inherited from a parent.

Comment: Indeed @MartijnPieters.

Comment: I'm not competent enough to write this as an answer, but in the interpreter `set(dir(C)) - set(dir(B))` seems to work (`C` inherits from `B`, `B` inherits from some class `A`).

Comment: What about *redefined* methods? So those methods for which `Ci` provides an implementation that differs from the same name existing on `Ci-1`?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for your comment, that works just perfect for the problem at hand - I do not have redefined methods in my case.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw If I were you I'd use Martijn's answer, I'm sure there are cases where the `dir` approach won't work.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: `dir()` is a debugging method and filters or adds names as deemed necessary. You'll not see a difference in most cases, but do read [what's the biggest difference between dir and \_\_dict\_\_ in python](//stackoverflow.com/a/14361362). It is also overkill for the 'no redefined methods' case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all names defined on the class itself in the [`__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) of a class; you can use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to list those more succinctly:

```
from types import FunctionType

for name, object in vars(Ci).items():
    if isinstance(object, FunctionType):
        print(name, 'is defined on Ci directly and not inherited')
```

You may need to vary the test for functions; I'm assuming here you only want plain function objects (which are bound into methods when looked up on the instance), but you may need to test for class or static methods or other callables too, depending on your use-case.

This will include names that have been re-defined; so these exist on the parent *too* but `Ci` provides a new implementation that masks that of a parent.

If you must find all names that uniquely belong to `Ci` and no parent provides, you'll have to filter on names that exist on the bases:

```
parent_defined = set().union(*(dir(b) for b in Ci.__bases__))

for name, object in vars(Ci).items():
    if name not in parent_defined and isinstance(object, FunctionType):
        print(name, 'is defined on Ci directly and not inherited')
```

Comment: Cool. What about using `callable` instead of `isinstance`? (You have a typo in that line, btw.) Also what about functions that are just attributes of the class object, but not defined there? (Take `X.foo = lambda: 42` for some class `X`.)

Comment: @timgeb: depends on the use-case. Should static and class methods count  (and those are *not* callable, they are bindable, producing a callable object)? Should classes set as attributes count?

Comment: @timgeb: there is *zero difference* between setting a function as an attribute on the class after the fact or defining it in the class body. `lambda` expressions still produce a function object.

Comment: Huh, what about being bound or unbound?

Comment: @timgeb: Nothing is bound when looking at `__dict__`. Binding takes place in `__getattribute__`, so you need to use `getattr(Ci, name)` to see if something bound or if it has a `__get__` method.

Comment: @timgeb: however, you then need to define more context; what should it bind *to*? The class or the instance? Both? You can't know which one until you execute the binding, which can have side-effects.

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering about the "zero difference" part. Is it truly true when considering binding?

Comment: @timgeb: there would only be a difference if something intercepted assignment to `foo` (e.g. an existing data descriptor like a `property` object or a `__setattr__` hook). Otherwise, assigning a function object to an attribute just sets that name in the `__dict__` object and it'll be bound just the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your last code does not work for me, nothing gets printed. FYI, all my methods have a decorator associated to it.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: if the decorators return a function object then there is no difference there. Are you sure your class doesn't use the same names as the parent class(es)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, there are exactly 6 methods right now which are newly defined in class `Cn`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just taking out: `and isinstance(object, FunctionType)`, does the trick, I get exactly what I wanted. For full disclosure, _all_ members of my class are methods, hence no need to specify `FunctionType` I guess.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: no, `vars()` returns **unbound objects**. Your decorators return objects that are not plain functions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters TBH, I do not know exactly how these decorators work. I am coding on my company's internal software system; FYI these decorators are used for _memoization_ purposes. I guess as you say that they don't return unbound objects.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw: Binding usually requires an *instance to bind to*. Functions are not the only objects that can be bound however. Anything with a `__get__` method can be, they are called descriptors, see the [Howto on the subject](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).